# BeautifulSoup4 | What is the easiest way for a BS4 beginner to quickly, and simply, gather text information from a table that has no IDs?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to create a web scraping program that gathers information from Wowpedia. (A wikia style website)

My primary concern right now is meaningfully being able to simply, so I can remember/reference for the future as I really struggle with this, gather information from a table when there are no reliable IDs to cite. Preferably, I would also like to do this without relying too much on individual CSS selectors, but if they are required I will happily oblige.

As an example, I will provide a simple code snippet I typed up to showcase how I would begin to tackle this problem.

```
# Troll Grabber Version 0.1

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Zul%27jin"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")


bio = soup.find("table", class_="infobox darktable")
print(bio)
```

This snippet of code will indeed grab the table that I want, and list all of the contents within. The thing I struggle with though, is getting meaningful information from it.

```
<table cellspacing="3" class="infobox darktable" style="border-spacing:3px;width:22em;width:21.5em;"><tbody><tr class="above-header"><th colspan="2" style="text-align:center;font-size:125%;font-weight:bold;padding:5px;"><span style="display:table;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;"><span style="display:table-row;"><span style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;padding-right:5px;width:1px;"><span class=""><a href="/wiki/Faction" title="Neutral"><img alt="Neutral" data-file-height="32" data-file-width="18" decoding="async" height="32" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/wowpedia/images/1/19/Neutral_32.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/18?cb=20110620212507" width="18"/></a></span></span><span style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;padding-right:2px;">Zul'jin</span></span></span></th></tr><tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
<a class="image" href="/wiki/File:Zul%27jinWallpaperCrop1.PNG" title="Image of Zul'jin"><img alt="Image of Zul'jin" data-file-height="653" data-file-width="469" decoding="async" height="278" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/wowpedia/images/7/7d/Zul%27jinWallpaperCrop1.PNG/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/200?cb=20071117013555" width="200"/></a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="text-align:left;background-color:transparent;">Title</th><td>
Warlord of Zul'Aman,<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-UVG140_1-0"><a href="#cite_note-UVG140-1">[1]</a></sup> <a href="/wiki/Chieftain" title="Chieftain">Chieftain</a> of the Amani<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-UVG140_1-1"><a href="#cite_note-UVG140-1">[1]</a></sup></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="text-align:left;background-color:transparent;">Gender</th><td>
Male</td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="text-align:left;background-color:transparent;">Race</th><td>
<a href="/wiki/Forest_troll" title="Forest troll">Forest troll</a> (Undead)</td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="text-align:left;background-color:transparent;">Class</th><td>
<a href="/wiki/Warrior" title="Warrior">Warrior</a><sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-2"><a href="#cite_note-2">[2]</a></sup></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="text-align:left;background-color:transparent;">Reaction</th><td>
<a href="/wiki/Alliance" title="Alliance"><span class="rep-friendly" title="Friendly">Alliance</span></a> <a href="/wiki/Horde" title="Horde"><span class="rep-friendly" title="Friendly">Horde</span></a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="text-align:left;background-color:transparent;">Former affiliation(s)</th><td>
<a href="/wiki/Amani_tribe" title="Amani tribe">Amani tribe</a>, <a href="/wiki/Old_Horde" title="Old Horde">Old Horde</a>, <a href="/wiki/Revantusk_tribe" title="Revantusk tribe">Revantusk tribe</a><sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-3"><a href="#cite_note-3">[3]</a></sup></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="text-align:left;background-color:transparent;">Former occupation(s)</th><td>
<a href="/wiki/Axethrower" title="Axethrower">Axe thrower</a>, Ruler of the Amani tribe and <a href="/wiki/Zul%27Aman" title="Zul'Aman">Zul'Aman</a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="text-align:left;background-color:transparent;">Location</th><td>
<a href="#Locations">Various</a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="text-align:left;background-color:transparent;">Status</th><td>
Deceased<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-4"><a href="#cite_note-4">[4]</a></sup></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

All of this is a real mouthful that is wrought with HTML elements, quotation marks, attributes, etc. With the information that I want buried within. In times of desperation or with simpler outputs, I've used long sequences of str.replace() and things like it to strip away all of this HTML. While I could use something like regex, I have to wonder that there's some better way to gather this information without having to take scissors to paper if you will.

Instead of this as the race output, for example:

```
<a href="/wiki/Forest_troll" title="Forest troll">Forest troll</a> (Undead)</td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="text-align:left;background-color:transparent;">Class</th><td>
```

An output more like this:

```
Race: Forest Troll (Undead)
```

For this project, I would like to achieve an output similar to this for all of the values in this table, but I haven't the faintest clue on how to pursue that.

I understand this is definitely something I could learn if I really set to reading the documentation, which I always have open (as well as other websites) while I code. But something so simple as gathering information without gathering *all of the HTML information* is something that eludes me. Commands like get_text() seem like a step in the right direction, until I realize they don't accept class arguments and seem intended for gathering every bit of text on the page.

To those willing to spend the time to help enlighten me, I thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

1. Since all the footnotes are under the class `reference`, you can remove them from the `soup` using the [`.decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) method. (Similar to my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67606652/12349734)).
2. The headers are under a `th` tag. Find that.
3. The other data is under a `td` followed by the previously found `th`. Find that by calling the [`.next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) method on the `th`.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Zul%27jin"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", class_="infobox darktable")

# Remove all the footnotes from the table using the `decompose()` method
for tag in table.find_all(class_="reference"):
    tag.decompose()

for th in table.find_all("th")[1:]:  # <-- Using `[1:]` since we don't want the image
    print(f"{th.text}:  {th.next_sibling.get_text(strip=True)}")
```

Output:

```
Title:  Warlord of Zul'Aman,Chieftainof the Amani
Gender:  Male
Race:  Forest troll(Undead)
Class:  Warrior
Reaction:  AllianceHorde
Former affiliation(s):  Amani tribe,Old Horde,Revantusk tribe
Former occupation(s):  Axe thrower, Ruler of the Amani tribe andZul'Aman
Location:  Various
Status:  Deceased
```

Comment: Fantastic, and very compact! I appreciated all of the answers, but having something so efficient really helped me understand how to tackle situations where I can't rely on IDs and the like!

Comment: @Senuvox Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 2):

You are actually quite close. You just want to select all the anchor/link tags within the table using `find_all`. Then you want to loop through the list of anchor tags and extract the relevant inner text.

```py
table = soup.find("table", class_="infobox darktable")

links = table.find_all("a")

races = []
for link in links:
    # try printing out link.attrs and link.string right here
    # to see why you need this if statement
    if "title" in link.attrs and link.string:
        races.append(link.string)

print(races)
```

XenonOverflows answer is also solid. This would allow you to utilize the table headers to grab even more information.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with `find_all("tr")`, which will return all the line in the bio. You can then iterate over the list it returns to get the text. You can add some rules to get the output you want.

```py
# Troll Grabber Version 0.1.1

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Zul%27jin"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")


table = soup.find("table", class_="infobox darktable")

for tag in table.find_all(class_="reference"):
    tag.decompose()

for item in table.find_all("tr"):
    try:
        title = item.find("th").text.strip()
        desc = item.find("td").text.strip()
        print(title + ": " + desc)
    except AttributeError:
        continue # We ignore the cases where there are no <th> attribute
```

Here, we iterate over all the  attribute, which is all the line in the table. We then `try:` to get an attribute , but if there are none then we just ignore this specific  (for example, the  with an image does not contain an attribute ).

Then, we get the text with `.text` from the  attribute, which is the table header attribute, which contains the name of the item, for example, Race or Class. We `strip()` the string so there are no whitespace. We also get the text from the  attribute which contains the description of the item, for example Forest troll (Undead).

Right now the output look like this:

```
Title: Warlord of Zul'Aman, Chieftain of the Amani
Gender: Male
Race: Forest troll (Undead)
Class: Warrior
Reaction: Alliance Horde
Former affiliation(s): Amani tribe, Old Horde, Revantusk tribe
Former occupation(s): Axe thrower, Ruler of the Amani tribe and Zul'Aman
Location: Various
Status: Deceased
```

**EDIT: I changed my answer based on what MendelG did. His answer was more pythonic and didn't used Regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd 

dfs = pd.read_html("https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Zul%27jin")
```

You'll get list of tables and you need only check which you need.

Comment: Introducing a new dependency is not answering the question. The question is how to accomplish this with BeautifulSoup